# PHP curl on https returns error 400, but on http => 301 => https 200, mangled GET path?

Tags: php, curl, https, php-curl, http-status-code-400

(I edited the title, see EDIT below: GET path in the *response* contains spaces, requested path does not.)

I am working for a company that uses a *"template system"* to enable their markets (different countries) to host small web apps and making them *"feel"* like part of the main market website by pulling header, navigation, footer of the main website via **curl**:

So a php script uses curl to pull a special empty CMS page that contains only the relevant elements and placeholders for the web app to replace. This way, the web apps always have the current legal footer, header and navigation links to the main sections on the CMS and feel like being part of the cms albeit being hosted on their own somewhere else.

In this case, depending on an i18n parameter in the url, the script is curling a different template for each of ~50 markets.

Now the curious case: This is working for all templates but one, which is returning error 400 when being curled via **https**.
But when curled via **http**, 301 is returned, then another request to the previously faulty **https** URL is made, only this time it returns 200.

Does not work:

```
*   Trying [server_ip]...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x562a5065a130)
* Connected to www.[company_name].pt ([server_ip]) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.[company_name].pt
*  start date: Aug 23 19:02:44 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Nov 21 19:02:43 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.[company_name].pt" matched cert's "*.[company_name].pt"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x562a5065a130)
> GET [path]   HTTP/2
Host: www.[company_name].pt
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Integrator https://[app_name].[company_name].com)
Accept:text/html
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive:115
Connection:keep-alive
Cache-Control:max-age=0

* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
* The requested URL returned error: 400 
* stopped the pause stream!
* Connection #0 to host www.[company_name].pt left intact
```

Does work:

```
*   Trying [server_ip]...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x562a5066c0f0)
* Connected to www.[company_name].pt ([server_ip]) port 80 (#0)
> GET [path]   HTTP/1.1
Host: www.[company_name].pt
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Integrator https://[app_name].[company_name].com)
Accept:text/html
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive:115
Connection:keep-alive
Cache-Control:max-age=0

< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 185
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://www.[company_name].pt/[path]
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host www.[company_name].pt left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://www.[company_name].pt/[path]'
*   Trying [server_ip]...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x562a5066c0f0)
* Connected to www.[company_name].pt ([server_ip]) port 443 (#1)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.[company_name].pt
*  start date: Aug 23 19:02:44 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Nov 21 19:02:43 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.[company_name].pt" matched cert's "*.[company_name].pt"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x562a5066c0f0)
> GET [path]
Host: www.[company_name].pt
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Integrator https://[app_name].[company_name].com)
Accept:text/html
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive:115
Connection:keep-alive
Cache-Control:max-age=0

* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 15305
< date: Thu, 22 Sep 2022 09:25:35 GMT
< server: Apache
< x-robots-tag: noindex
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< referrer-policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
< cache-control: public, max-age=3600
< expires: Thu, 22 Sep 2022 10:25:35 GMT
< pragma: public
< accept-ranges: bytes
< content-encoding: gzip
< 
* Connection #1 to host www.[company_name].pt left intact
```

Calling the template in the browser works, with http and https.
curl from CLI works also for both http and https and returns 200, the error only occurs with PHP.

The script (a bit blown up for error search):

```
function curl($url){
    $headers[]  = "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Integrator https://[app_name].[company_name].com)";
    $headers[]  = "Accept:text/html";
    $headers[]  = "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate";
    $headers[]  = "Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $headers[]  = "Keep-Alive:115";
    $headers[]  = "Connection:keep-alive";
    $headers[]  = "Cache-Control:max-age=0";

    /**/debug_to_console("init curl");
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+'));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    if(curl_errno($curl)){
        debug_to_console("curl url: " . $url);
        debug_to_console("curl error: " . curl_error($curl));
        //echo 'Request Error:' . curl_error($curl);
    }
    echo "Verbose information:\n<pre>", !rewind($verbose),  htmlspecialchars(stream_get_contents($verbose)), "</pre>\n";
    curl_close($curl);
    return $data;
}
```

As mentioned, on other templates from other markets (on the same server) this is working fine. And I was told, that the instances are duplicated, so they all should have the same settings. Again, they are all on the same server. Unfortunately, I can't get them to check further until I'm pointing them into the right direction what to look at.

Tests with ssllabs.com showed no differences between the instances.

Being a Front End Dev, I'm really not getting any further at this point, after trying multiple suggestions for similar errors. I'm suspecting a wrong setting on that instance, but what instructions/hints can I give the server team?

Sorry I had to remove IPs and company/app names.
Thank you.

**Edit:** Not sure if this is relevant, for some reason, the line `> GET /[path] HTTP/2` is different in the faulty curl attempt:

Every successful curl has *one space* between the path and HTTP/2, the faulty one has *three spaces* between the path and HTTP/2.
When using http instead of https, the line also has three spaces `> GET /[path]   HTTP/1.1)`, gets the 301 response and after redirect, the new attempt has only one space `> GET /[path] HTTP/2`.

The URL is not the problem, it is absolutely identical to other instances where there is no problem. Does the server add a space character itself on the initial curl attempt? What could cause added spaces? This has to be server side, the other instances don't mangle the initial GET path.

Comment: The one that "does not work" does not have a redirct. You have two CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER . Did you mean for one of them to be CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  The PHP manual say this about CURLOPT_SSLVERSION: Your best bet is to not set this and let it use the default.

Comment: @Misunderstood thanks, you are correct, the redirect seems to fix the problem.
As mentioned in the Edit, it seems that the initial GET path gets mangled somehow: Two additional space characters are added to the end of the URL. But not in the code. And that's what I don't understand: Where does it happen?
When calling http, the redirect to https uses the correct URL without spaces.
All ~ 50 URLs are called the same way, none has space chars. It just happens with this one URL. And most of them are on the same server!